# Restar horas de un datetime en MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

Tengo un campo el cual es un datetime, este campo me retorna la siguiente fecha/hora:

```
2018-05-16 14:37:45
```

Lo que me gustaría es poder restarle 5 horas a esa fecha y que quede así:

```
2018-05-16 09:37:45
```

Lo pude lograr con la función de [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) pero me gusta creer que podría haber otra manera más fácil de lograr lo que quiero. ¿Alguna otra manera de lograrlo que sea más fácil?

```
DATE_ADD(ov.hora_llegada, INTERVAL -5 HOUR)
```

Comment: Lo que utilizas es algo de lo más óptimo, puedes usar `HOUR(ov.hora_llegada) - INVERVAL 5 HOUR` también

Comment: La función propia para restar a una fecha es [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), por ejemplo: `SELECT DATE_SUB(ov.hora_llegada, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)...` apreciarás que la única diferencia es que aquí se pone **el número a restar en positivo**. Por *más fácil* yo entendería más adecuada, más mejor, más óptima... entonces esta es tu función. Recurrir a otros métodos sería complicarse, o invertir esfuerzos en *reinventar la rueda*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL tiene [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(ov.hora_llegada, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

Y luego usarla como desee, por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE prueba SET ov.hora_llegada = DATE_SUB(ov.hora_llegada, INTERVAL 5 HOUR);
```

Si desea probarlo primero para asegurarse de que está haciendo lo que quiere:

```
SELECT ov.hora_llegada, DATE_SUB(ov.hora_llegada, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) FROM prueba;
```