# Consulta MySQL comparando fecha mientras se resta una hora específica

Tags: mysql

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una tabla en la cual tengo un campo datetime, dicho campo se crea automáticamente con la expresión CURRENT_TIMESTAMP el cual toma la fecha y hora del servidor, ahora bien necesito filtrar los registros que fueron creados el día de hoy, para ello ocupo el query que menciono abajo, el detalle es que quisiera restarle 6 horas a la fecha original y sobre esa fecha realizar mi consulta, es posible eso? Lo anterior es debido a que mi información se está alojando en un servidor que utiliza UTC y hay una diferencia de -6 horas con mi país.

Mi consulta actual es:

```
select * from bd_pjeo.mitabla
WHERE LEFT(campofecha,10) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: auxiliate de `DATE_SUB` con ayuda de `INTERVAL` para poder hacer lo que necesitas, aquí una respuesta de la comunidad al respecto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/restar-horas-de-un-datetime-en-mysql

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, he agregado lo siguiente a mi condición where left((FechaAcceso - interval 6 hour),10) = CURDATE();

Comment: considera agregarlo como respuesta y explicarlo

Answer (score 2):

En [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) la zona horaria la podes consultar en las variables

@@global.time_zone y @@session.time_zone;

Si tenes privilegios podes modificar la variable global

```
    SET GLOBAL time_zone = "-06:00";
```

o sino podes modificar la variable por conexión.

```
    SET time_zone = "-06:00";
```

Si no modificas la zona horaria del server, podes hacer la conversión con la función https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

```
select CONVERT_TZ(campofecha,'+00:00','-06:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes estar refiriéndote a algo así. Sustituye la función NOW() por la fecha que envíes al servidor en formato 'aaaa-mm-dd':

```
SELECT * FROM ejemplos WHERE date(instante)=date(NOW()-INTERVAL 6 HOUR);

-- tabla
CREATE TABLE ejemplos(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ejemplo int,
  instante timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)  
  );

-- datos
INSERT INTO ejemplos (ejemplo)
  VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```